# Angular mouseover-equivalent touch event in handling multiple selection

Tags: angular, touch-event

I am working with Angular 4, and I have a component containing a list of `<box>` components. I need to enable user to **select multiple boxes** in the parent component.

In the [first version](http://plnkr.co/edit/JKLgMdyGgWZcrAeDE2cy?p=preview), I handle mouse events with `mousedown, mouseover and mouseup`. For each mouse event, `a box component emits its id to the parent component`.
User can select multiple box by click a box and drag the mouse to other boxes.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JKLgMdyGgWZcrAeDE2cy?p=preview)

box.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'box',
  styles: [`

  `],
  template: `
    <div class="box-container"
      (mousedown)="onMouseDown()"
      (mouseover)="onMouseOver()"
      (mouseup)="onMouseUp()">

     {{ id }}
   </div>
  `
})
export class BoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: number;

  @Output() mouseDown: EventEmitter<number>;
  @Output() mouseOver: EventEmitter<number>;
  @Output() mouseUp: EventEmitter<number>;

  constructor() {
    this.mouseDown = new EventEmitter<number>();
    this.mouseOver = new EventEmitter<number>();
    this.mouseUp = new EventEmitter<number>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onMouseDown(): void {
    this.mouseDown.emit((this.id));
  }

  onMouseOver(): void {
    this.mouseOver.emit((this.id));
  }

  onMouseUp(): void {
    this.mouseUp.emit((this.id));
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <box *ngFor="let id of ids" [id]="id"
           (mouseDown)="onMouseDown($event)"
           (mouseOver)="onMouseOver($event)"
           (mouseUp)="onMouseUp($event)">
      </box>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div style="display: flex;">
      Selected Ids: <span *ngFor="let id of selectedIds" style="padding-left: 10px;">{{ id }}</span>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  ids: [number];
  enableTracking: boolean;
  selectedIds: Set<number>;

  constructor() {

    this.enableTracking = false;
    this.ids  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    this.selectedIds = new Set<number>();
  }

  onMouseDown(boxId: number): void {
    this.enableTracking = true;
    this.selectedIds.clear();
    this.selectedIds.add(boxId);
  }

  onMouseOver(boxId: number): void {
    if (this.enableTracking) {
      this.selectedIds.add(boxId);  
    }
  }

  onMouseUp(boxId: number): void {
    this.enableTracking = false;

    console.log('Selected Ids: ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedIds));
  }
}
```

In the [second version](http://plnkr.co/edit/VvswK5eBBjiqKIsy6ZV8?p=preview), I try to achieve the same thing using touch events: `touchstart, touchmove and touchend`.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VvswK5eBBjiqKIsy6ZV8?p=preview)

box.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'box',
  styles: [`

  `],
  template: `
    <div class="box-container"
      (touchstart)="onTouchStart()"
      (touchmove)="onTouchMove()"
      (touchend)="onTouchEnd()">

     {{ id }}
   </div>
  `
})
export class BoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: number;

  @Output() touchStart: EventEmitter<number>;
  @Output() touchMove: EventEmitter<number>;
  @Output() touchEnd: EventEmitter<number>;

  constructor() {
    this.touchStart = new EventEmitter<number>();
    this.touchMove = new EventEmitter<number>();
    this.touchEnd = new EventEmitter<number>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onTouchStart(): void {
    this.touchStart.emit((this.id));
  }

  onTouchMove(): void {
    this.touchMove.emit((this.id));
  }

  onTouchEnd(): void {
    this.touchEnd.emit((this.id));
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <box *ngFor="let id of ids" [id]="id"
           (touchStart)="onTouchStart($event)"
           (touchMove)="onTouchMove($event)"
           (touchEnd)="onTouchEnd($event)">
      </box>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div style="display: flex;">
      Selected Ids: <span *ngFor="let id of selectedIds" style="padding-left: 10px;">{{ id }}</span>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  ids: [number];
  enableTracking: boolean;
  selectedIds: Set<number>;

  constructor() {

    this.enableTracking = false;
    this.ids  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    this.selectedIds = new Set<number>();
  }

  onTouchStart(boxId: number): void {
    this.enableTracking = true;
    this.selectedIds.clear();
    this.selectedIds.add(boxId);
  }

  onTouchMove(boxId: number): void {
    if (this.enableTracking) {
      this.selectedIds.add(boxId);  
    }
  }

  onTouchEnd(boxId: number): void {
    this.enableTracking = false;

    console.log('Selected Ids: ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedIds));
  }
}
```

However, it does not work as expected because the `touchmove` event always emit the `box-id associated to touchstart` event.
In the first version, each time I move to another box component, `mouseover` emits the box-id of the `current-active` box component.

How should I handle this multiple selection in touch devices?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but this workaround might be helpful:

1. Add index data to the DOM element as an attribute, which can be used to find the angular element
2. Use elementFromPoint to find the actual DOM element you are looking for
3. Parse index data from the element, and use it to select the corresponding angular element.

I use this function, which contains some filtering:

```
public touchMoveHandler(event) {
    // Allow dragging only if it was started on a specific sets of classes
    if (!event.touches[0].target.classList.contains('free') || event.touches[0].target.classList.contains('inactive-for-user')) {
        return;
    }

    // Prevent scroll by touch
    event.preventDefault();

    // Find the actual DOM element under the coordinates
    const targetElement = (document.elementFromPoint(event.changedTouches[0].clientX, event.changedTouches[0].clientY));

    // Only match elements that I want to listen
    if (!targetElement.classList.contains('free')) {
        return;
    }

    // Get element index attribute that points to my array
    const id = targetElement['getAttribute']('data-block-index');

    // Find it in my array
    const currentBlock = this.blocks[id];

    ...
}
```

In the HTML:

```
        (touchmove)="touchMoveHandler($event)"
        [attr.data-block-index]="i"
```

Not the most elegant way, couldn't find better.

Comment: Unfortunately, `elementFromPoint` seems to always return the `app-root` instead of any element at the location.